# How do I make a certain text style larger?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I wrote up a post in WordPress that included some code samples.  I used the "preformatted" style for the code sample, which gives a nice monospace font and doesn't screw up multiple spaces, and everything looks great...

...except that it's *tiny!*  The text of the code samples comes out at something ridiculously small, like 8 pt or something.  The HTML isn't much help; it's only producing this text by wrapping it in a `<pre>` tag.  So I figure the bad size setting has to be coming from my style sheet.

I don't know a thing about CSS, though, and trying to look through the style sheet isn't very helpful.  Does anyone know how I can find what's causing the `<pre>` tag to generate tiny text and tweak it to make the text size larger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be several different stylesheets in your Wordpress installation and you have to read them all, in order to find out what's causing the problem. You should search for a definition of "pre", but, given you don't know much about CSS, you may have to do several tests to find out which one you should alter.

I believe an easier way is to install a plugin for code snippets, such as [this](http://blog.hackerforhire.org/code-snippet/).

Comment: THANK YOU!  That looks much better!

Comment: Eager to see the results on your blog. Glad I helped.

Comment: http://tech.turbu-rpg.com/13/whats-in-a-name-less-method It's about the low-level details of the way closures are implemented in Delphi as anonymous methods.  I'm gonna have to tweak the syntax highlighter a bit, but it looks pretty good.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a style like so:

```
pre {
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

CSS allows you to apply styling to block-level items as well as classes and ID's.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, put the following:

```
pre { font-size: 16px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for "pre" in the CSS files, there's probably a font-size value defined.  You can change this to a larger value to increase the size.  Here's an example [styling pre tags](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/styling-pre-tags-with-css-code-block/).